# DragEntered and DragExited methods javaFX8

Tags: drag-and-drop, draggable, javafx-8

When the **second** time I move dragged object to the area and then exit it, It doesnt change back to original color, just like if DrageExited movement wasnt registered this next time. When I move card for the first time to the area and then exit, everything is fine, color changes when I enter and exit the area.

In the picture I made drag straight up to the first row then straight back down to row 4 and then to the left.
[image]

```
public void makeDeckDraggable(){
        for(CardValue cardValue: CardValue.values()){
            for(CardSuit cardSuit: CardSuit.values()){
                Card nextCard = (Card) deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].getCenter();
                nextCard.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

                nextCard.setOnDragDetected( event -> {
                    Dragboard db = nextCard.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
                    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                    content.putImage(nextCard.getImage());
                    db.setContent(content);
                });

                deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].setOnDragOver(event -> {
                    if(event.getGestureSource() instanceof Card)
                        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
                });

                String oldCardPaneStyle = "-fx-border-color: red; -fx-border-width: 0.1px;"
                        + "-fx-background-color: radial-gradient( focus-angle 0.0deg, focus-distance 0.0%, center 50.0% 50.0%, radius 100.0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.16091954708099365) 0.0, rgba(153,179,255,0.2183908075094223) 100.0 )";
                deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].setOnDragEntered(event -> {
                        if(event.getGestureSource() instanceof Card)
                            deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTSALMON,null,null)));
                });
                deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].setOnDragExited(event -> {
                        if(event.getGestureSource() instanceof Card)
                            deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].setStyle(oldCardPaneStyle);
                });

                deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].setOnDragDropped(event -> {
                    if(event.getGestureSource() instanceof Card){
                        if(deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].getCenter() != null){ // when target is not empty we need to switch cards
                            CardPane pane =  (CardPane) ((Card) event.getGestureSource()).getParent();
                            pane.setCenter(deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].getCenter());
                        }
                        deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].setCenter((Card)event.getGestureSource());
                        event.setDropCompleted(true);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe theres a way to handle it with css style?

EDIT. Ive found out that to make colors return to orginal I need to move a card from opposite area. If I made this red colors by moving card from deck below, then I have to move card in empty deck above. And vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt consider it might be a difference but I found the missing part.

`setBackground` and `setStyle` works differently, so:

```
deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].setOnDragEntered(event -> {
                        if(event.getGestureSource() instanceof Card)
                            deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
                });
                deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].setOnDragExited(event -> {
                        if(event.getGestureSource() instanceof Card){
                            String oldCardPaneStyle = "-fx-border-color: red; -fx-border-width: 0.1px;"
                                    + "-fx-background-color: radial-gradient( focus-angle 0.0deg, focus-distance 0.0%, center 50.0% 50.0%, radius 100.0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.16091954708099365) 0.0, rgba(153,179,255,0.2183908075094223) 100.0 )";
                            deck[cardValue.value][cardSuit.value].setStyle(oldCardPaneStyle);
                        }
                });
```

I still wonder if this might be done by CSS styling tho...